# Can i use FLOOR() in JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: jpa

With regular MySQL I can artificially group records against a common "ID" with a query like

```
SELECT FLOOR(ID / 4) as GroupID FROM Table;
```

Assuming my IDs are sequential, this gives me groups of 4 with the same GroupID.

My question is, can this be done in JPA with a CriteriaQuery? I can see there is a CriteriaBuilder.prod() method (which can be used for division), but how to I convert the result to a straight integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see there are actually conversion methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#toLong%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29